# Woocommerce - Getting meta data by product IDs

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, orders

I'm looking to return all the meta data for every order by product id associated with the current user. I've tried various methods which return empty arrays. I'm looking to access the ID, Key & Value meta data

Anyone suggest where i'm going wrong? Thanks

```
$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$table_items = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_items";
$table_itemmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_itemmeta";
$orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";

$orders_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT $table_items.order_id
FROM $table_itemmeta, $table_items, $table_posts
WHERE $table_items.order_item_id = $table_itemmeta.order_item_id
AND $table_items.order_id = $table_posts.ID
AND $table_posts.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
ORDER BY $table_items.order_item_id DESC"
);
```

The query above returns the order ids below which are correct.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 881
    [1] => 708
)
```

My loop through all orders

```
foreach ($orders_ids as $key => $value) {

    $orders = wc_get_order($value);

    foreach ($orders->get_items() as $item ){

        $item_meta = $item->get_meta();
        $item_meta_data = $item->get_meta_data();
        $item_formatted_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
        $item_formatted_data_true = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( '_', true );

        print_r($item_meta); // returns empty array
        print_r($item_meta_data); // returns example below
        print_r($item_formatted_data); // returns empty array
        print_r($item_formatted_data_true); // returns empty array

    }
}
```

This is my output using this code above

```
Array
(
    [0] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
            [current_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 646
                    [key] => yith_booking_data
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [from] => 1603152000
                            [to] => 1603411200
                            [duration] => 3
                            [person_types] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_services] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_service_quantities] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1602161920
                        )

                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 646
                    [key] => yith_booking_data
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [from] => 1603152000
                            [to] => 1603411200
                            [duration] => 3
                            [person_types] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_services] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_service_quantities] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1602161920
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
            [current_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 647
                    [key] => _booking_id
                    [value] => 882
                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 647
                    [key] => _booking_id
                    [value] => 882
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
            [current_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 451
                    [key] => yith_booking_data
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [from] => 1600905600
                            [to] => 1600992000
                            [duration] => 1
                            [person_types] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_services] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_service_quantities] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1600955166
                        )

                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 451
                    [key] => yith_booking_data
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [from] => 1600905600
                            [to] => 1600992000
                            [duration] => 1
                            [person_types] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_services] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [booking_service_quantities] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1600955166
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
            [current_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 452
                    [key] => _booking_id
                    [value] => 709
                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 452
                    [key] => _booking_id
                    [value] => 709
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Use this code in the loop

```
foreach ($orders_ids as $key => $value) {

    $orders = wc_get_order($value);

    foreach ($orders->get_items() as $item ){

        $item_meta_data = $item->get_meta_data();
        $item_key_meta = $item_meta_data[0]->value; <- add code
        print_r($item_key_meta);

    }
}
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [from] => 1603152000
    [to] => 1603411200
    [duration] => 3
    [person_types] => Array
        (
        )

    [booking_services] => Array
        (
        )

    [booking_service_quantities] => Array
        (
        )

    [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1602161920
)
Array
(
    [from] => 1600905600
    [to] => 1600992000
    [duration] => 1
    [person_types] => Array
        (
        )

    [booking_services] => Array
        (
        )

    [booking_service_quantities] => Array
        (
        )

    [_added-to-cart-timestamp] => 1600955166
)
```